# How can I add my program to system program list (Ubuntu 14.04)?

Tags: package-management, path, executable

I made a my program in c++ and generated its executable but every time I need to use my program I need to change my directory to the folder and then execute it.

How do I make my program run like an installed package so that I don't have to shift my directory every time I need to run it?

Comment: May [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/465109/256099) help?